# How to add string value to cell in SQL using php?

Tags: php, sql, sql-update, varchar

I am trying to update varchar cell in SQL users table. Now the value of groups_id is `3`. `$last_id = 4`. I want to change it to `3, 4`. Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

With this code the value remains the same

```
$sql = "UPDATE registration.users SET groups_id = groups_id+', $last_id' WHERE username = '$user_name'";
$update_groups_id = $db->query($sql);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$val = $groups_id . ", ".$last_id;
$sql = "UPDATE registration.users SET `groups_id` = '$val' WHERE username = '$user_name'";
$update_groups_id = $db->query($sql);
```

your SQL query is wrong, you are not concatenating variables properly, try doing this way, I think it should help you

Comment: Thanks. Do i need to use SELECT in order to get $groups_id?

Comment: yes, @KibbleShop, first select `$groups_id` otherwise it will show undefined variable error

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax fault in your `$sql` object as you use `+', $last_id'`. If you want to append in PHP you can use `.` in string context

Also I'm pretty sure you can leave the `''` from the variables so `'$last_id'` will become `$last_id`

But more important is that you do not check for any security issues. I hope $user_name and $last_id are not just taken from the input as SQL injections are possible.

I recommend you to look at [mysqli_prepare](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) and [mysqli_bind](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Comment: Thanks. I will add checking. For your recomendation I tried ```groups_id = groups_id+''.$last_id``` it still shows and error. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @KibbleShop I assumed you used + as an operator to append a new string. If that is what you want you have to use . -> "I have a variable a ". $a